# Annotate a Django Queryset using a 'related_name' across a ManyToMany relationship (NO 'Count', 'Avg', 'Max', ...)

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, annotations, many-to-many

I have models in my code similar to the following:

```
class CompanyProject(models.Model):
    """ This class holds project related information read in from the 'project'
        custom 'manage.py' command.
    """

    project_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    project_worktype = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=False, null=False)
    last_seen = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)


    def get_project_subtypes(self):
        subtypes = self.project_subtype.all()
        return [ subtype.project_subtype for subtype in subtypes ]

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['project_number']

class CompanySubType(models.Model):
    class CompanySubTypeChoices(models.TextChoices):
        G1A = '1A', _('1A')
        G1B = '1B', _('1B')
        G2A = '2A', _('2A')
        G2B = '2B', _('2B')
        G3A = '3A', _('3A')
        G3B = '3B', _('3B')

    company_project = models.ManyToManyField(CompanyProject, related_name='project_subtype')
    project_subtype = models.CharField(blank=False, choices=CompanySubTypeChoices.choices, max_length=2, null=False)


class ListEntry(models.Model):

    list_project = models.OneToOneField(CompanyProject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='list_project')
    list_reviewer = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
```

I would like to return a set of annotated `ListEntry` objects annotated with a list of ALL of the project subtypes identified with the `ListEntry` project.

Eventually, I need to be able to pass this annotated data to a Django REST Framework serializer but I need to get the annotation working like I want it to first.

My problem is that I can annotate just fine doing something like this:

```
list_entry_qs = ListEntry.objects.prefetch_related(
    'list_project', 'list_reviewer'
).annotate(
    subtypes=F('list_pmatt__project_subtype__project_subtype')
).all()
```

and it works just fine.  The issue I am having is that the query set that's returned from that command duplicates the `list_entry` object if it has more than one `subtype` annotation.

For example, if a project numbered 1234 has two project subtypes, '1A' and '3A', I get two `list_entry` objects:  one with `subtype` annotation '1A' and a separate `list_entry` object for the same project with `subtype` annotation '3A'.

I would like a SINGLE object returned for project 1234 that has a `subtype` annotation of '1A', '2A' that will eventually be serialized to a JSON object.

There has to be an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, After spending literally 8 hours on this, I finally found out how to do it:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates.general import ArrayAgg

q = ListEntry.objects.prefetch_related(
    'list_pmatt', 'list_reviewer', 'list_pmatt__project_subtype'
).annotate(
    my_subtype=ArrayAgg('list_pmatt__project_subtype__project_subtype')
)
```

```
>>> q[2].my_subtype
['1A', '3A']
```

Comment: Very interesting feature, thanks for sharing.